# How to Prevent Nested Decorators in Autofac When Using Interface Inheritance?

Tags: c#, .net, dependency-injection, decorator, autofac

I have a .NET 7.0 application where I am using Autofac as my DI container. I have two interfaces `IReadonlyRepository<T>` and `IRepository<T>`, where `IRepository<T>` inherits from `IReadonlyRepository<T>`.

My Repository classes implement these interfaces. I also have a decorator, `LoggingRepository<T>`, which wraps `IRepository<T>`, logs each call to the repository's methods, and delegates the call to the wrapped `IRepository<T>` instance. Here is the code for `LoggingRepository<T>`:

```cs
class LoggingRepository<T> : IRepository<T>
{
    private readonly IRepository<T> _repository;

    public LoggingRepository(IRepository<T> repository)
    {
        _repository = repository;
    }

    public IEnumerable<T> List()
    {
        Console.WriteLine($"Calling {_repository.GetType().Name}<{typeof(T).Name}>.List()");
        return _repository.List();
    }
}
```

Here's how I register my classes and decorators in the DI container:

```cs
builder.RegisterGeneric(typeof(Repository<>))
    .As(typeof(IRepository<>))
    .As(typeof(IReadonlyRepository<>))
    .InstancePerLifetimeScope();

builder.RegisterGenericDecorator(typeof(LoggingRepository<>), typeof(IRepository<>));
builder.RegisterGenericDecorator(typeof(LoggingRepository<>), typeof(IReadonlyRepository<>));
```

I have also tried using named registration to potentially circumvent this issue, but it didn't change the behavior.

The problem I am facing is that when I request an instance of `IReadonlyRepository<T>`, it appears that `LoggingRepository<T>` ends up decorating another instance of `LoggingRepository<T>`, which in turn decorates the `Repository<T>` instance. This is not the intended behavior - I only want a single instance of `LoggingRepository<T>` to decorate `Repository<T>`.

In effect, the system seems to be nesting decorators because IRepository also implements IReadonlyRepository.

How can I prevent Autofac from nesting decorators in this situation? What's the proper way to register these decorators when dealing with interface inheritance to ensure they are not nested?

Comment: split your `LoggingRepository` into two classes, one per interface

Comment: @Steven I'd consider this a last resort solution.  Ideally your DI container shouldn't dictate your code design and make it more complicated than it needs to.

Comment: Yes, ideally, but in the end every DI Container will still have a design philosophy or limitations that will dictate certain design choices. I myself even consider the fact that you can register `LoggingRepository<T>` as decorator for `IReadonlyRepository<T>` a design flaw in Autofac, because `LoggingRepository<T>` is not a decorator for `IReadonlyRepository<T>`, but for `IRepository<T>`. If Autofac was blocking this registration, you wouldn't have been asking this question at all.

Comment: Generics and decorators could definitely use some help. We have a sort-of-related [issue here](https://github.com/autofac/Autofac/issues/1330). Would love a PR to fix up things folks see as challenging.